# get currently selected list in javascript on load - sharepoint 2010

Tags: javascript, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, sharepoint-clientobject

I'm currently trying to find out, how to get a reference to currently selected list in sharepoint from javascript. I can get it if I know the title, or id, but I want it to get the list dynamically depending on where the user is. I have this code (in my modal dialog):

```
ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(init, 'sp.js');

function init() {
    var context = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    var web = context.get_web();
    var list = web.get_lists().getById(SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList());
}
```

The problem is that `SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList()` returns null. There is probably some other script I need to wait for - but which one?

Comment: Related Q&A on SharePoint.SE about the current list item, maybe it will help: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/11169/how-do-you-get-the-current-list-item-in-javascript

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out. `SP.ListOperation.Selection.getSelectedList()` doesn't work inside of a modal dialog. I needed to pass list ID from the parent window.

Answer (score 0):

You may have found a bug in SharePoint web services (not that that's particularly surprising, given the sparseness of their API).

See [here](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010customization/thread/19eb1a7c-bcc9-44c5-a547-768c8a9386d1). I didn't look too carefully but BananaRepublic seemed to have a workaround for this problem; I don't know the exact context, so I don't know if it will work for you or not.